# Problem setting parent div width the same as child div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="head_title">
  <img src="/path/to/image.png">
  <h1 id="entryTitle">
    <!--Cufon Font-->
  </h1>
</div>
```

I want the img element to stretch to the full width of the 'head_title' div. The trouble arrives when I try and set the 'head_title' div to be as wide as the 'entryTitle' child h1 tag.  Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
.head_title {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
}
.head_title img {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
}
.head_title h1 {
        color:#fff;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;left:0;
        z-index:1;
        padding:0 0 0 5px;
}
```

The underlying img element contains the background for the parent div - I don't want to use the CSS background-image attribute because the parent div's width will constantly be changing and I don't want it to cut off a static background image.

I tried using JavaScript's `outerWidth` and jQuery's `.css("width")` and `.width()` methods but nothing seems to work.

Comment: can you not just stretch the background image? also if the underlay is in a fluid container how do you handle the overflow? basically what i'm getting at is; any functionality you can get via an underlay as far as UI is concerned you can achieve with the background property.

Comment: No point in the `.head_title {display: block;}` as div is a block anyways. And basically, `height` doesn't work with simple `block`. It must be `inline-block`.

Comment: So you want the img to be as a background for h1? Are you cutting some psd or something? If you would provide some screenshot or sketch, you would get an answer right away. Currently the question is not that clear and your code only makes things more complicated.

Comment: also it is very hard to debug your code with the limited about you are providing. The parent DIV is `float:left;` which (without being modified by some other element or styles) will keep the width as small as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm slicing up a PSD and skinning a site. Thanks for the hints about the display:block and float properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These elements have a width of 0px, because you assigned the `float:left` property to `div.head_title`. Because of this float definition, the div doesn't stretch to the full width.

The image has a width of 100%, 100% of zero is still zero. The h1 element is positioned absolutely, so that element doesn't increase the width either.

To increase the width of `div.head_title`, you have to specify a width (`width:!00%`, for example), or remove the float property.

Comment: You were right about the float. I removed the float property, set the `h1` element's width to 'auto' and used jQuery's width() to manually set the `div.head_title`'s width.

Answer (score 1):

or you could also do this....

```
<div class="head_title">
  <img src="/path/to/image.png">
  <h1 id="entryTitle">
    <!--Cufon Font-->
  </h1>
</div>

.head_title{
    float: left;
    position:relative;height:40px;
}
.head_title img {
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1; width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
.head_title h1{color:#999;padding:0 0 0 5px;}
```

[sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/UEt9j/)